# How do I denote content from curl's user flag (-u) in Typhoeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, typhoeus

I want to translate a curl request to a Typhoeus request.  Curl request:

```
@response = %x{curl -i https://track.customer.io/api/v1/customers/#{@client.id} \
        -X PUT \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -u #{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]}:#{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]} \
        -d '{
          "email":"#{@client.email}",
          "name":"#{@client.name}",
          "id":"#{@client.id}",
          "created_at":"#{@client.created_at.to_time.to_i}"}'}
```

Typhoeus request:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
    "https://track.customer.io/api/v1/customers/4", 
    ssl_verifypeer: false,
    method: :put,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" => "application/json",
        "user_agent" => "#{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]}:#{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]}"},
    body: '{
    "email":"first@last.com", 
    "name":"Name is here",
    "id":"4",
    "created_at":"#{Time.now}"}')
```

When I run the Typhoeus request, I get a response saying `unauthorized` which I believe indicates my user info is incorrect.  How can I set the -u flag equivalent in a Typhoeus request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the -u flag equivalent in a Typhoeus request?

Use the `userpwd` key within the options hash, e.g:

```
url = "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/john/pwd1234"
Typhoeus::Request.new(url, userpwd: "john:pwd1234").run
```

Comment: You should have made a mistake with the user and/or password. This API uses Basic Auth as auth scheme, which is precisely what `-u` or `userpwd:` enables. Why do you use twice `APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]`? You are supposed to use your secret API key as password.

Comment: Correct, thanks.  For anyone reading this, the correct curl line is `-u #{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:site_id]}:#{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]}`  and the correct Typhoeus line is `Typhoeus::Request.new(url, userpwd: "#{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:site_id]}:#{APP_CONFIG[:customerio][:api_key]").run`